# Arduino UNO analog input pins

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm a student working with the Arduino UNO
There's this question always bugging me for the analog input pins, how many samples does it take per cycle.
I know it has 10 bit resolution meaning 0-5v would be 0-1023.I think since Arduino UNO uses ATMEGA 328(8 bit) then maybe 256 samples per cycle, but people say 128 bits per cycle. I'm confused.

Comment: What do you mean by "cycle"? What do you mean by "bits per cycle"?

Answer (score 2):

The sample rate is nowhere close, neither in samples nor bits per cycle. The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf) gives the conversion time for a *single* sample relative to the ADC clock as:

> A normal conversion takes 13 ADC clock cycles. The first conversion after the ADC is switched on (ADEN in
> ADCSRA is set) takes 25 ADC clock cycles in order to initialize the analog circuitry.

The ADC clock itself is taken from the system clock, with a prescaler ranging from /2 to /128, with the condition that the ADC clock ought to be no higher than 200 kHz. This yields a roughly 15 kSps sampling rate at best.

Answer (score 0):

The ATMega328 uses a successive approximation ADC, that means, that the ADC has to do multiple comparison until it has a result. Therefore, he need multiple cycles, in the datasheet you can find the time for the conversion, measured in number of cycles.

From the datasheet of the ATMega328, Table 23-1
[image: Image from the datasheet]